# Generating a linked-data website with Apache jena

Tags: jena

Is it possible to generate a linked-data website with Apache Jena.

i.e. generate the web pages for the resources.
e.g. Like such: https://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type
OR
https://id.nlm.nih.gov/mesh/D000069544.html

If not, is there a tool for generating those?

Comment: https://github.com/apache/jena/discussions/2284

Answer (score 1):

I think that this project might be along the lines you are looking for: https://github.com/SemanticComputing/sampo-ui

> Sampo-UI – A framework for building user interfaces for semantic portals

Answer (score 1):

I was directed to look at LDF: https://www.w3.org/TR/ldp/
https://www.w3.org/wiki/LDP_Implementations